# How can I add array data to the object if field exist/not exist in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, nosql, insert-update, findandmodify

This is my expected result:

```
 "ForgotPassword": [
     {
       "UpdatedOn": ISODate("2017-12-06T11:23:23.0Z"),
    },
     {
       "UpdatedOn": ISODate("2017-12-06T11:45:13.0Z"),
    }
  ]
```

And this what I am getting:

```
"ForgotPassword": {
     "UpdatedOn": [
       ISODate("2017-12-20T11:48:15.0Z"),
       ISODate("2017-12-20T11:48:30.0Z"),
       ISODate("2017-12-21T11:57:21.0Z") 
    ] 
  }
```

Actually Forgot password field will not present in the collection document.

When I add the **first** time it should create **Forgotpassword** field and inside **updatedon** should store

**And**

when I add the **second** time the inside the **Forgotpassword**, **updatedon** should repeat for me it is storing inside **updateon**

This is my query:

```
 $updateQuery  =   $queryUpdate->update(

 array("CollaboratorId"=>(int)$collaboratorId), //query condition

 array('$addToSet'=>array('ForgotPassword.UpdatedOn'=>$currentDate)),

 array('upsert'=>1)

 );
```

Comment: Try `array('$addToSet'=>array('ForgotPassword'=>array('UpdatedOn'=>$currentDate)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryUpdate->findAndModify( 
array("CollaboratorId"=> (int)$collaboratorId),
array('$addToSet'=> array('ForgotPassword' =>array("UpdatedOn" => $currentDate))),
array('new' => 1,"upsert"=>1)
);
```

With **upsert** and **new** and **findandmodify** and **addtoset** it is working